# MySQL Case Sensitive Tables Conversion

Tags: php, mysql, windows, linux

I have a PHP codebase that was written to address our MySQL tables in mixed case.  For example, `xar_intakeformgenerator_ChangeLog`.

Our code also runs on windows, and before we knew any better, we imported several databases on to a Windows server.  This resulted in Windows MySQL changing all the table names to lower case. (`xar_intakeformgenerator_changelog`).  We now know how to prevent that from happening to new databases. (`Set lower_case_table_names`) And, the code runs fine on the Windows servers because MySQL just doesn't care about the case of the tables on Windows.

Here's the problem.  The Windows server is giving us grief and we need to move all of the databases off to a Linux server.  Because all of the table names have converted to lower case, the code will NOT work on Linux.  Luckily, Xaraya creates table mappings.  So, in theory, I could set up a new code base for these databases and change the mappings of every module to use the lower case tables.  Or, we could manually change the table names after we import them onto the Linux machine to get the table case correct.

changing `lower_case_table_names` does not correct the databases that were mangled before the flag was set.  These all have the lower case table names.

I'm not wild about either option.  Does anybody know an ingenious way to handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK. I found my answer.

On the Linux server, I needed to run the following to change all the table names in my Linux generated databases to lower case:

1. How to produce a SQL script that renames all tables in a schema to its lower case form:

   ```
   select concat('rename table ', table_name, ' to ' , lower(table_name) , ';') 
   from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'your_schema_name';
   ```
2. Renamed the databases in `phpmyadmin` to lowercase names.
3. Modified the `my.cnf` on the Linux server to use `lower_case_table_names=1`
4. Restarted mysql.

After this, my code would work with the lower case table names.  So, I was able to import the Windows ones and have the same code base work on both.

Comment: oops. I skipped step 1 and completed the remaining steps. Now I dont see my upper case tables in phpmyadmin. Now when I do step 1, I am unable to rename the tables. Is it okay to manually rename the files to smaller case?

Comment: `your_schema_name` refers to your database name, you can check this in `information_schema.TABLES`

Comment: This does not work for me on OS X Mojave (10.14)  MAMP 5.1 with MySQL 5.7.23 in MySQLWorkbench 6.3.10.
The statement is performed without errors with green checkbox but no changes are made. When you try to rename a table in another name and back to old name in lower case does work. Adding the keyword 'binary' does not help.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly *(had the same kind of problem a while back -- but I stopped working on that project before we decided which solution to adopt...)*, there is a configuration option which says how tablenames should be used (case-sensitive or not case-sensitive).

Here's what I found : [Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Quoting that page :

> If you are using MySQL on only one
>   platform, you do not normally have to
>   change the `lower_case_table_names`
>   variable from its default value.
>   However, you may encounter
>   difficulties if you want to transfer
>   tables between platforms that differ
>   in file system case sensitivity. For
>   example, on Unix, you can have two
>   different tables named `my_table` and
>   `MY_TABLE`, but on Windows these two
>   names are considered identical. To
>   avoid data transfer problems arising
>   from lettercase of database or table
>   names, you have two options:
>
> - Use `lower_case_table_names=1` on all systems. The main disadvantage with
>     this is that when you use `SHOW TABLES`
>     or `SHOW DATABASES`, you do not see the
>     names in their original lettercase.
>
>   - Use `lower_case_table_names=0` on Unix and `lower_case_table_names=2` on
>       Windows. This preserves the lettercase
>       of database and table names.

*(There is more I didn't copy-paste ; so going to read that page might be a good idea ;-) )*

Hope this will help...

Comment: yes, this is the setting that will prevent it from changing the case.  However, it has already changed the case on this set of databases.

Unfortunately, setting this flag doesn't change the case back after windows has already mangled it.

Comment: Oh :-( Thanks for providing us with the solution you found, though!

Comment: @PascalMARTIN can you guide me from where i can change the value of `lower_case_table_names` im using win7 and xampp

Answer (score 0):

lower_case_table_names

For Windows, it defaults to "make everything lower case" (1). Set it to 2:"Case insensitive but keep the case as it is".

These changes go into your my.cnf

Comment: As noted above, we made this setting change.  However, we have databases that are already mangled.