# Mysql - Rename all tables and columns to lower case?

Tags: mysql

I recently transferred a database from a windows box to a linux box. The tables are mixed between lower and upper case names. I need a way to rename all tables and columns to lowercase. Is that possible?

I see in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262258/mysql-case-sensitive-tables-conversion/1263470#1263470) it's possible for tables, but have not found anything that deals with column names.

Comment: +1, CamelCase Make your world upside down...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try to do exact same thing with Information_Schema.Columns table

EDIT:
Something like

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' CHANGE `', COLUMN_NAME, '` `',
LOWER(COLUMN_NAME), '` ', COLUMN_TYPE, ';')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{your schema name}'
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work; command appears to have succeeded, but a `describe **tablename**` shows capitalized columns.

Comment: Granted, maybe I just need to restart MySQL. I'm doing this on a shared host, so not sure if that is or isn't the case.

Comment: It didn't work form me initially, because TextEdit on Mac messes around with the single quotes. They were changed to something else during copy and paste.

Comment: i dont think that this query accounts for primary key columns with auto increment, for example. The 'COLUMN_TYPE' does not include auto increment or default values fo rthe columns.

Comment: WARNING: All columns that has auto-increment will lose auto-increment

Answer (score 11):

You can use this script proposed by Anders Eriksson on [MySQL Website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html):

```
 select concat('rename table ', table_name, ' to ' , lower(table_name) , ';') from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'your_schema_name';
```

Comment: So, when I do this and run the subsequent result, it tells me the table already exists.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe used builtin functions LOWER() UPPER().
http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_function_upper_lower.php

```
alter table [table name] change [old column name] [new column name] varchar (50);
```

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions were not complete enough for me.  They dropped column attributes like auto_increment, default values, and Not Null.  Additionally, I did not want to change columns in information_schema and mysql.

Warning: I did not research all column attribute combinations.  Just the set that allowed me to convert my database. There could be more constants like CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in your database.

I used a few variations of the below to determine what was in my database.

```
SELECT distinct COLUMN_DEFAULT FROM information_schema.columns
```

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
select 
CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', '`', t.TABLE_NAME, '`', ' CHANGE `', c.COLUMN_NAME, '`',
    ' `', LOWER(`COLUMN_NAME`), '` ', COLUMN_TYPE,
IF (IS_NULLABLE = "YES", ' ', ' NOT NULL'), 
IF (IS_NULLABLE = "YES",
    IF (COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NULL, 'DEFAULT NULL', IF (COLUMN_DEFAULT = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', ' DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', CONCAT(' DEFAULT ', '''', COLUMN_DEFAULT, ''''))),
    IF (COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL, IF (COLUMN_DEFAULT = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', ' DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', CONCAT(' DEFAULT ', '''', COLUMN_DEFAULT, '''') ), '') ) ,
' ', EXTRA, ';')
from 
information_schema.tables t
JOIN 
information_schema.columns c
ON (c.table_name = t.table_name)
WHERE t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
AND t.table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'mysql')
INTO OUT FILE '/tmp/ColumnsToLowerCase.sql'
```

Time saving notes:
To output to a file you have to login to the database with sufficient rights.
I have root access so I logged in as root, but cut and past of the results works too if you have to.

Comment: This works well but i needed to add the DISTINCT keyword to the select otherwise i got duplicate records returned.

Answer (score 1):

OK i have modified Dave Benson's answer to add the DISTINCT keyword (to prevent duplicate records being returned) and also to check for nullable timestamp columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', '`', t.TABLE_NAME, '`', ' CHANGE `', c.COLUMN_NAME, '`', ' `', LOWER(`COLUMN_NAME`), '` ', COLUMN_TYPE,
IF (IS_NULLABLE = "YES", ' ', ' NOT NULL'), IF (IS_NULLABLE = "YES", IF (COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NULL, IF (COLUMN_TYPE = 'TIMESTAMP', 'NULL DEFAULT NULL', 'DEFAULT NULL'), IF (COLUMN_DEFAULT = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', ' DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', CONCAT(' DEFAULT ', '''', COLUMN_DEFAULT, ''''))), IF (COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL,IF (COLUMN_DEFAULT = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', ' DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', CONCAT(' DEFAULT ', '''', COLUMN_DEFAULT, '''')),'')), ' ', EXTRA, ';')
FROM information_schema.tables t
JOIN information_schema.columns c ON (c.table_name = t.table_name)
WHERE t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
AND c.table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'mysql')
INTO OUT FILE '/tmp/ColumnsToLowerCase.sql'
```

Answer (score 0):

A better version of @Dave Benson, which get just your database tables and fix Current_timestamp

```
select
CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', '`', t.TABLE_NAME, '`', ' CHANGE `', c.COLUMN_NAME, '`',
    ' `', LOWER(`COLUMN_NAME`), '` ', COLUMN_TYPE,
IF (IS_NULLABLE = "YES", ' ', ' NOT NULL'),
IF (IS_NULLABLE = "YES",
    IF (COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NULL, 'NULL DEFAULT NULL', IF (COLUMN_DEFAULT = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', CONCAT(' NULL DEFAULT ', '''', COLUMN_DEFAULT, ''''))),
    IF (COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL, IF (COLUMN_DEFAULT = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', ' DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', CONCAT(' DEFAULT ', '''', COLUMN_DEFAULT, '''') ), '') ) ,
' ', EXTRA, ';')
from
information_schema.tables t
JOIN
information_schema.columns c
USING(`table_name`, `table_schema`)
WHERE t.table_schema = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME'
ORDER BY `TABLE_NAME` ASC
```