# Mysql change all table names to lower case

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have got 10 tables in mysql all starting with uppercase, I was wondering if can change all of them to lowercase with one query rather than 20?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659684/why-my-tables-names-are-converted-into-lowercase-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [Amy Anuszewski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1263470/552116) answer

```
select concat('rename table ', table_name, ' to ' , lower(table_name) , ';')from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'your_schema_name';
```

Comment: What is table_schema?

Comment: table_schema is the database name. To show also the databases without any tables: SELECT s. schema_name, t. table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA  --- check this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html

Comment: this query redirected me to information_schema table but didn't change the table names

Comment: Go through Amy Anuszewski answer link